# GetRequestStream() is throwing time out exception when posting data to HTTPS url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, https, httprequest

I'm calling an API hosted on Apache server to post data. I'm using HttpWebRequest to perform POST in C#.

API has both normal HTTP and secure layer (HTTPS) PORT on the server. When I call HTTP URL it works perfectly fine. However, when I call HTTPS it gives me time-out exception (at GetRequestStream() function). Any insights? I'm using VS 2010, .Net framework 3.5 and C#. Here is the code block:

```
string json_value = jsonSerializer.Serialize(data);


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://server-url-xxxx.com");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json_value);
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        System.IO.Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
```

EDIT: 
The console program suggested by Peter works fine. But when I add data (in JSON format) that needs to be posted to the API, it throws out operation timed out exception. Here is the code that I add to console based application and it throws error.

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json_value);
request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
```

Comment: Can you try it without the ProtocolVersion and ContentType

Comment: also get wireshark and have a look at what is happening across the wire. check that the target server accepts crossdomain calls.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I added ProtocolVersion and ContentType but looks like it didn't help much.I will check with wireshark, but since Python app can easily GET/POST to API I believe server is accepting cross-domain calls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you with your specific problem but you should consider Disposing some of those objects when you are finished with them. I was doing something like this recently and wrapping stuff up in using statements seems to clean up a bunch of timeout exceptions for me.

```
            using (var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                if (reqStream == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

              //do whatever

            }
```

also check these things

- Is the server serving https in your local dev environment?
- Have you set up your bindings *.443 (https) properly?
- Do you need to set credentials on the request?
- Is it your application pool account accessing the https resources or is it your account being passed through?
- Have you thought about using WebClient instead?

  ```
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
      {               
          using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("https://server-url-xxxx.com"))
          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
          {
              MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
          }
      }
  ```

EDIT:

make a request from console.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Run()
    {

       var request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://server-url-xxxx.com");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using(var response = new StreamReader(reqStream )
            {
              Console.WriteLine(response.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1. No it is not serving 2. Yes 3. No. 4. Can you elaborate on that? I didn't get it. 5. I tried WebClient but in .OpenRead it throws operation timed out error

Comment: One more update - I have setup simple Python application to access same API over HTTPS and its working absolutely fine. So looks like only .Net is problematic. Not sure why.

Comment: are you running cassini, iisexpress, or iis?

Comment: can you try it in a console application.

Comment: I'm running this application in local dev env. on Cassini. I'm sorry and this may sound noob, but how do you try it in console application?

Comment: add a console application to your solution. put the bit of code that makes the webrequest in Main and then use Console.WriteLine to see the result

Comment: Again the same issue. .OpenRead throws operation timed out error. Do you think it might be because of I'm using Cassini?

Comment: I'll try the program you've posted btw.

Comment: If you can get the console program working I think you will want to try your web application IISExpress. You can do that by right clicking the project and click the menu option to set it up.

Comment: Cool. I've edited my original question with results from console app. However, I'll give a try to IISExpress.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the same issue.   It seems like it is solved for me.   I went through all my code making sure to invoke **webResponse.Close()** and/or **responseStream.Close()** for all my HttpWebResponse objects.  The documentation indicates that you can close the stream or the HttpWebResponse object.   Calling both is not harmful, so I did.   Not closing the responses may cause the application to run out of connections for reuse, and this seems to affect the HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream as far as I can observe in my code.

Comment: it happened to me when using REST API for Azure Mobile Services

Comment: In effect, this is the same as the accepted answer from @Peter

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://server-url-xxxx.com");
    req.Method = "POST";
    string json_value = jsonSerializer.Serialize(data); //Body data
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json_value);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    Stream GETResponseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GETResponseStream);
    var response = sr.ReadToEnd(); //Response
    resp.Close(); //Close response
    sr.Close(); //Close StreamReader
```

And review the URI:

- Reserved characters. Send reserved characters by the URI can bring
     problems  `! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? # [ ]`
- URI Length: You should not exceed 2000 characters

Comment: `StreamWriter` will call `Flush()` & `Close()` in it's `Dispose()` method which will be called for your using block.

Comment: Thank you so much, by closing Response and StreamReader it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this, too. I wanted to simulate hundreds of users with a Console app. When simulating only one user, everything was fine. But with more users came the Timeout exception all the time.

Timeout occurs because by default the ConnectionLimit=2 to a ServicePoint (aka website).
Very good article to read:  https://venkateshnarayanan.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/httpwebrequest-reuse-of-tcp-connections/

What you can do is:

1) make more ConnectionGroups within a servicePoint, because ConnectionLimit is per ConnectionGroups.

2) or you just simply increase the connection limit.

See my solution:

```
private HttpWebRequest CreateHttpWebRequest<U>(string userSessionID, string method, string fullUrl, U uploadData)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(fullUrl);
    req.Method = method; // GET PUT POST DELETE
    req.ConnectionGroupName = userSessionID;  // We make separate connection-groups for each user session. Within a group connections can be reused.
    req.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 10;    // The default value of 2 within a ConnectionGroup caused me always a "Timeout exception" because a user's 1-3 concurrent WebRequests within a second.
    req.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 5 * 1000;  // (5 sec) default was 100000 (100 sec).  Max idle time for a connection within a ConnectionGroup for reuse before closing
    Log("Statistics: The sum of connections of all connectiongroups within the ServicePoint: " + req.ServicePoint.CurrentConnections; // just for statistics

    if (uploadData != null)
    {
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        SerializeToJson(uploadData, req.GetRequestStream());
    }
    return req;
}

/// <summary>Serializes and writes obj to the requestStream and closes the stream. Uses JSON serialization from System.Runtime.Serialization.</summary>        
public void SerializeToJson(object obj, Stream requestStream)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    json.WriteObject(requestStream, obj);            
    requestStream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set timeout property, check it here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/69637/Setting-timeout-property-for-System-Net-WebClient

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've set that but still doesn't work.